# Python desktop FPS displaying in label

Tags: python, label, pyqt5, frame-rate

I can't manage to display current fps on the label.
The problem is i want it to loop and keep changing forever, not to be set once. My idea was to loop it but untill sys.exit() the controlls like my label_fps does not apear.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog
from main_view import Ui_MainWindow


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = ApplicationWindow()
    application.show()

    def fps_display():
        start_time = time.time()
        counter = 1
        # All the logic()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        time_now = time.time()
        fps = str((counter / (time_now - start_time)))
        application.ui.label_fps.setText(fps)
    #while(True): does not work
    fps_display()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out, the Qt app isn't displayed until `sys.exit()` is called and you therefore can't stay in a loop before this.

I think what you therefore need to do is use a `QTimer`. This will emit a signal every *n* milliseconds. This signal can then be connected to your `fps_display()` function so that it is called every time the signal is emitted. For example, you can create a `QTimer` that will emit a signal every 0.1 seconds using:

```
timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(100)  # 100 milliseconds = 0.1 seconds
timer.start()  # Set the timer running
```

The signal that will be emitted when the timer has run out is `timeout()`. It is therefore this signal that we want to connect to the function that handles the updating of the FPS label as so:

```
timer.timeout.connect(fps_display)
```

Now, putting this together and moving the location of `fps_display()` so that it is a method of the `ApplicationWindow` class, we get:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, pyqtSlot  # Import new bits needed
from main_view import Ui_MainWindow


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Add in creating and connecting the timer 
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(100)  # 100 milliseconds = 0.1 seconds
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.fps_display)  # Connect timeout signal to function
        self.timer.start()  # Set the timer running

    @pyqtSlot()  # Decorator to tell PyQt this method is a slot that accepts no arguments
    def fps_display(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        counter = 1
        # All the logic()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        time_now = time.time()
        fps = str((counter / (time_now - start_time)))
        self.ui.label_fps.setText(fps)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = ApplicationWindow()
    application.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have moved `fps_display()` for convenience, but it by no means needs to be a method of `ApplicationWindow` to be called by the timer's signal.

That should now hopefully be able to do what you are after. I have had to make a slightly different script to yours as I don't have the UI file you are using so hopefully I have converted back over okay and it all works!

Comment: Works fine for now. The signal was the solution I was looking for. I'll have to make some changes i.e. taking the core logic outside of the fps_display(), because it has to work constantly but now I can make take label change every 0.1s (or other time period) i want. Thanks.

Comment: @Nav I'm glad I was able to help. If you could set it as the accepted answer if you think it is good enough that would be brilliant. Thanks.